# DOM elements Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have append

```
cardBodyButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    listGroup.append(addTodo());
})
```

and I have a function

```
var addTodo = function(){
    var todoList = document.createElement('li');

    todoList.className = "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between";
    todoList.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Todo 5'));

    var todoList_a = document.createElement('a');
    todoList_a.className = "delete-item";
    todoList_a.setAttribute('href','#');

    var todoList_a_i = document.createElement('i');
    todoList_a_i.className = "fa fa-remove";

    todoList_a.append(todoList_a_i);

    todoList.append(todoList_a);  
};
```

I am trying to call function in append but it says undefined. What is wrong here?

Comment: it could be something relevant to scope, can you show example clearly how you are calling them

Comment: i fixed ))) i forgot to return inside the addtodo function